# IdentityServer4 Find which grant in PersistedGrantStore applies to current refresh token

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

We have a web api that is using IdentityServer4 for authentication. One of the requirements is to send back a list of "Active Sessions" for the user. We are using an EntityFramework based custom IPersistedGrantStore to store the grants in SQL.

Is there any way I can take the information from the web request (I can see the full bearer token by the time the request gets to the API) and find the grant that applies to it in the database?

The 'key' in the row is not the token itself. I am not changing tokens every time they are refreshed. Is there some means of hashing the token and comparing it to the existing keys to say "This is your current session?"

The idea being I can "Log out of all sessions (Except this one)"

My current best guess is looking up the row based on user id, client id and creation time. But I would like to be able to get it by key if possible.

Comment: first of all, are you sure you need the list of active refresh tokens? you say *active sessions* and that's totally other story. session is usually just a cookie keeping the list of the Clients, requested an *identity token* during... current user session : )

Comment: Perhaps you should ask: How to log out of all sessions (except this one). IPersistedGrantStore seems not the right service to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up creating a custom ITicketStore for the cookie middleware (via the SessionStore config property) to store cookie values (and thus the SubjectId they relate to) in the PersistedGrants table. We use the `session_id` property in the `AuthenticationTicket` (which is the value that ends up in the session ID cookie and in tokens as the `sid` claim) as the key and a type of `auth_ticket`.

Once you have this in place it's trivial to delete (and thus end) any authentication sessions related to the user AND exclude the current session should you wish.

Comment: We are currently planning to only issue clients auth with refresh tokens, so ew can rely on the persistedgrants table, but if we need to add new clients that don't request the "offline_access" that could be an issue, as you could be signed in, yet not have a refresh token. Yeah, just deleting the rows there works for us. I'm currently using the token created time and client id and comparing that to the current values in the bearer token to 'best guess' the current session.